# Can not use Edward 1.3.5 with Tensorflow 1.14.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, edward

I am trying to use Edward library for deploying a PPCA model and facing difficulties while installing it on windows. I successfully installed Edward 1.3.5 using  (pip install edward ) and tensorflow 1.14.0 using (pip install tensorflow) but when I try to import edward in jupyter notebook , I get the following error

cannot import name 'set_shapes_for_outputs' from 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops

I tried looking into issues opened here (https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/issues/882) and here (https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/issues/893)  but nothing worked.

If anyone has any recommendations and/or suggestions, that would be great!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All I did to solve this issue was, I created a new conda environment, downgraded python to 3.6.5 (anything older than 3.7.0 works fine) and downgraded TensorFlow to version 1.3.0 (anything older than 1.6.0 works fine).